# Magento2 How To Export Product Custom Attribute With Value

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom

I have export product from backend and getting custom product attribute but it shows empty data in csv file.
does anyone know how i can export custom attribute with value?

Comment: it should add value in CSV. please check products assign those attribute values.

Comment: yes i already  check value is there in product edit page as well as product grid

Answer (score 2):

In default Product Export, all custom attributes get appeared under "additional_attributes" header in the export separated by a comma (,). Please check CSV file again.

And one more thing you can use this free module: https://bsscommerce.com/custom-product-attribute-export-for-magento-2.html

It is a very useful extension for this problem.

Comment: thanks but i also tired this extension but not getting my attribute value,and yes make sure i have create custom product type and assign custom attribute to that product type